# Custom Camera not saving the whole image

Tags: java, android, camera

I have built an android custom camera in this way:

```
    //CameraActivity.java

    public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraPreview.OnCameraStatusListener {

        String path, TAG = "CameraActivity";
        private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

            Button takePhoto = findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
            takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "===takePhoto()===");

                    if (cameraPreview != null) {
                        cameraPreview.takePicture();
                    }
                }
            });

            //Start camera
            initCameraPreview();
        }

    private void initCameraPreview() {
        Log.e(TAG, "===initCameraPreview()===");

        cameraPreview = findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        cameraPreview.setOnCameraStatusListener(this);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onCameraStopped(byte[] data) throws JSONException {
        Log.e("TAG", "===onCameraStopped===");
        File mSaveFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        saveToFile(data, mSaveFile);
    }

    public File getOutputMediaFile() {

        File mediaStorageDir =
            new     File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CustomCameraPics");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "myPic_" + time + ".png");

        path = file.getPath();
        Log.e("imagePath", path);

        return file;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void saveToFile(byte[] bytes, File file) throws JSONException {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        try {

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            Log.e("Image", "Saved");
            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Image Saved",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//activity_camera.xml 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sukshi.mycamera.CameraActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.shank.mycamera.CameraPreview
            android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Take pic"
            android:id="@+id/takePhoto"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

    //CameraPreview.java 

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private OnCameraStatusListener listener;

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    private Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                camera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (null != listener) {
                try {
                    listener.onCameraStopped(data);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void takePicture() {
        Log.e(TAG, "===takePicture()===");
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public interface OnCameraStatusListener {
        void onCameraStopped(byte[] data) throws JSONException;
    }

    public void setOnCameraStatusListener(OnCameraStatusListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "==surfaceCreated==");
        camera = getCameraInstance();

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error setting camera preview", e);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        //update()

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.startPreview();

            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        Log.e(TAG, "==surfaceChanged==");
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "==surfaceDestroyed==");
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        int cameraId = 0;
        boolean frontCameraFound = false;

        try {
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);

                if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    cameraId = i;
                    frontCameraFound = true;
                }
            }

            if (frontCameraFound) {
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            } else {
                camera = Camera.open();
            }
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            parameters.setRotation(270);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "getCamera failed");
        }
        return camera;
    }
}
```

It saves the image when you click 'TAKE PIC' button.

My requirement: the whole image that the user can see on the screen in preview should be saved.

The problem I'm facing is that in some of the phones the image/bitmap saved doesn't contain everything that is shown to the user on screen.

Comment: can you please share image as well , like what is you are getting in above and what do you actually want. ?

Comment: There is no requirement for the camera APIs to return the same images for preview as for taking pictures. In particular, if their aspect ratios differ, then it is guaranteed that previews and pictures will be different.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way that I can save only and whole of what is visible on the preview

Comment: I know of no reliable way of doing that. You can try cropping the photo to have the same aspect ratio as the preview image, but that does not mean that the photo will exactly match the preview image.

Answer (score 1):

As @CommonsWare has explained, there is no requirement that a captured picture should be same as preview picture. You can skip `camera.takePicture()` altogether, and in your `cameraPreview.takePicture()`, save the latest preview frame as bitmap.

The advantages of this approach are that your are guaranteed that the same image as the user sees in the preview is saved, and it happens with no delay.

The drawback is that the resolution and quality for image returned from `camera.takePicture()` may be noticeably better.

If you not satisfied with preview frame quality, you can use the same size for [setPreviewSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setPreviewSize(int,%20int)) and for [setPictureSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setPictureSize(int,%20int)), if the size is supported for both [getSupportedPreviewSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getSupportedPreviewSizes()) and [getSupportedPictureSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getSupportedPictureSizes()): *usually* you can find a satisfactory pair.

If you are not satisfied with the preview frame resolution, at least choose the same **aspect ratio** for [setPreviewSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setPreviewSize(int,%20int)) and for [setPictureSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#setPictureSize(int,%20int)). Some devices produce really weird results when the two don't match.

But note that these steps can not guarantee that the captured image will be the same as previewed, even only because `takePicture()` inevitably happens with some delay.

---

One more remark: if you target **Android N** and above, consider switching from the *deprecated* Camera API to the **camera2** API.